# Can anyone identify the resistors in the picture?

Tags: resistors, identification

[image] Can anyone identify the resistors in the picture ?

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking? They look like 1W power resistors to me, but if you want to know their composition or manufacturer you're out of luck.

Comment: Estimates of the power rating would be a lot more accurate with dimensions. It is always good to include a ruler in the picture.

Comment: Thanks guys, the PCB is approx 52 mm in length and 15 mm wide. It's a component from a trigger in a nail gun

Comment: Incidentally, that bottom one seems to have cracked. It may be broken.

Comment: Hey Fran from a functional perspective , they are equivalent to 0.75 Ω . The body length of 15 mm could be 2W or 3W each,  This adds to the DCR of the solenoid to reduce battery surge current. (DCR+R/2)  Non-inductive is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be a 1.5 Ω non-inductive of unknown tolerance.

Based on this:

[image]

I read it as (after SunnySkyGuyEE75's comment):  brown, green, gold, brown, black

Which translates to:  15, with a 0.1 multiplier, unknown tolerance, and non-inductive.

Comment: The "unknown brown/black" band looks pretty definitively brown to me.

Comment: Irfanview  reads it as Brown, Green, Gold .. Brown,  Black,  but for me I recall almost 20yrs ago  our plant nurse telling after a pastel colour test with hidden numbers, that as Eng Mgr of a contract manufacturing board shop and having read resistors OK for most of my life, that I was "color-blind" !  no big deal to not distinguish black and brown.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oMEe.png   so 1.5 Ohms  but brown has 2x as much red

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 What a great idea to use Irfanview to determine the color!  I will adjust my answer then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used this [resistance calculator](http://resistor.cherryjourney.pt/). Use four bands brown, green, gold and brown, ignoring the last black band which means non-inductive. So that gives me 1.5 ohm +- 1% non-inductive resistor.

Comment: Small 'o' for ohm. Fixed. (SI units named after a person are lowercase when spelled out but have their symbols capitalised. 'V' for volt, 'K' for kelvin, etc.) SI also recommends a space between the number and the units. (Same as you wouldn't write "5apples", but "5 apples".